# Connecting to AWS Managed Cassandra with Perl

Tags: perl, cassandra, amazon-keyspaces

I am trying to connect to AWS Managed Cassandra using Perl. It's not working due to a vague error `Error 0: Internal Server Error`.

Using the [DBD::Cassandra](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::Cassandra) Library, I can connect to self hosted Cassandra clusters, but not AWS Cassandra. I think I have the AWS Root CA correct because it verifies with `openssl s_client -connect cassandra.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:9142`

```
DBI->connect("dbi:Cassandra:host=cassandra.us-east-1.amazonaws.com;port=9142;tls=1;keyspace=keyspace",
 "**username**", "**password**");
```

The error response from the connection is

```
Unable to connect to any Cassandra server. 
  Last error: On cassandra.us-east-1.amazonaws.com: 
  Error 0: Internal Server Error
```

I can also connect using the `cqlsh` client and verified that the connection details are correct.

Any hints or a working example would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be setting the keyspace. Doing this either on the connection or subsequently with `use keyspace` results in a `Error 0: Internal Server Error` response from the server.

Also note that AWS Managed Cassandra only supports consistency `local_quorum`. The following will result in a valid connection:

```
DBI->connect("dbi:Cassandra:host=cassandra.us-east-1.amazonaws.com;
   port=9142;tls=1;consistency=local_quorum",
   "**username**", "**password**");
```

Since there are issues setting the keyspace, tables must be referenced using `keyspace.tablename` in queries.